# MySQL sum amounts for transactions related to loans, in reverse order

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I'm trying to add an amount living in a transactions table, but the adding must be done taking the transactions in reversed order, grouped by a loan they belong to. Let me put some examples:

```
Transactions
tid    loanid    amount    entrydate
------------------------------------
1      1         1,500     2013-06-01
2      2         1,500     2013-06-01
3      1         1,000     2013-06-02
4      3         2,300     2013-06-04
5      5         2,000     2013-06-04
6      1         1,100     2013-06-07
7      2         1,000     2013-06-09
|      |         |         |


Loans
loanid
------
1
2
3
4
5
|
```

As you can see, there's no transactions for loanid 4, just to make clear the point that there's no obligation for the transactions to exist for **every** loan.

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to sum up the amounts for the transactions of each loan. This first approach achieves this:

```
SELECT tr.tid,
       l.loanid,
       tr.entrydate,
       tr.amount,
       @prevLoan:=l.loanid prevloan,
       @amnt:=if(@prevLoan:=l.loanid, @amnt+tr.amount, tr.amount) totAmnt

FROM (SELECT * FROM Transactions) tr

JOIN (SELECT @prevLoan:=0, @amnt:=0) t

JOIN Loans l
     ON l.loanid = tr.loanid


GROUP BY l.loanid, tr.tid
```

Which achieves something like this:

```
tid    loanid    entrydate    amount    prevloan    totAmnt
-----------------------------------------------------------
1      1         2013-06-01   1,500     1           1,500
3      1         2013-06-02   1,000     1           2,500
6      1         2013-06-07   1,100     1           3,600  <-- final result for loanid=1
2      2         2013-06-01   1,500     2           1,500
7      2         2013-06-09   1,000     2           2,500  <-- final result for loanid=2
4      3         2013-06-04   2,300     3           2,300  <-- final result for loanid=3
5      5         2013-06-04   2,000     5           2,000  <-- final result for loanid=5
|      |         |            |         |           |
```

As you can see, for each loan, the amount of the transactions belonging to it are getting sumed up in the totAmnt column, so the last transaction of each loan has the total sum of the transactions for the same loan.

Now.... what I actually need is something to get the sum to be done in reversed order. I mean, for the same transactions of each loan, the sum still gets the same result, but I need the sum to be done from the last transaction of each loan up to the first one.

I've tried the following, but to no avail (it's the same query as the last one, but with an Order By DESC on the FROM transactions table):

```
SELECT tr.tid,
       l.loanid,
       tr.entrydate,
       tr.amount,
       @prevLoan:=l.loanid prevloan,
       @amnt:=if(@prevLoan:=l.loanid, @amnt+tr.amount, tr.amount) totAmnt

FROM (SELECT * FROM Transactions ORDER BY tr.entrydate DESC) tr

JOIN (SELECT @prevLoan:=0, @amnt:=0) t

JOIN Loans l
     ON l.loanid = tr.loanid


GROUP BY l.loanid, tr.tid
```

I'm using tr.entrydate because is a more familiar way to say the order criteria, and besides that's what policy says is the valid order criteria, tid may say something but entrydate is the ordering column of the Transactions table...

Using the previous query, I just get the same results I get with the first query, so I guess something must be missing there. What I need is to get results as the following:

```
tid    loanid    entrydate    amount    prevloan    totAmnt
-----------------------------------------------------------
6      1         2013-06-07   1,100     1           1,100
3      1         2013-06-02   1,000     1           2,100
1      1         2013-06-01   1,500     1           3,600  <-- final result for loanid=1
7      2         2013-06-09   1,000     2           1,000
2      2         2013-06-01   1,500     2           2,500  <-- final result for loanid=2
4      3         2013-06-04   2,300     3           2,300  <-- final result for loanid=3
5      5         2013-06-04   2,000     5           2,000  <-- final result for loanid=5
|      |         |            |         |           |
```

As you can see the sum for each loanid gets the same final result, but the sum is done for the transactions in reversed order...

Hope all this mess is clear... How can I achieve such a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be VERY close...  I think you have two small adjustments.  First, dont use the outer GROUP BY as you are not doing any aggregations (sum, min, max, avg, etc).  Second, when querying your transaction table, just order that by the loan ID FIRST, THEN the date descending... This way all the loan IDs are in proper order grouped together, but within each loan, THEY are sorted descending order as you are looking for.  Also, adjust your @prevLoan AFTER you have accumulated so the current record can be compared to the next.  You are starting the @variable to zero so it won't match the first loan ID on the first run anyhow.  Finally, you don't even need the join to the loan table since the transaction table has the loan ID to use as basis of comparison test.  Since the inner-most query is ordered by loan and then entry date descending, you should not need it again at the outer query.

```
SELECT 
      tr.tid,
      tr.loanid,
      tr.entrydate,
      tr.amount,
      @amnt := if( @prevLoan = tr.loanid, @amnt+tr.amount, tr.amount) totAmnt,
      @prevLoan := tr.loanid prevloan
   FROM 
      ( SELECT * 
           FROM Transactions 
           ORDER BY loanid, entrydate DESC) tr

      JOIN (SELECT @prevLoan := 0, 
                   @amnt := 0) t
```

Alternate Solution??  Per my comment, it looks like you want the high totals and shrinking down... Is this closer?

```
SELECT 
      tr.tid,
      tr.loanid,
      tr.entrydate,
      tr.amount,
      trTotals.TotalLoans - if( @prevLoan = tr.loanid, @amnt, 0 ) as NewBal,
      @amnt := if( @prevLoan = tr.loanid, @amnt+tr.amount, tr.amount) runningTotals,
      @prevLoan := tr.loanid prevloan
   FROM 
      ( SELECT * 
           FROM Transactions 
           ORDER BY loanid, entrydate DESC) tr

      JOIN ( SELECT loanid, sum( amount ) as TotalLoans
                FROM Transactions 
                group by loanid ) trTotals
         on tr.loanid = trTotals.loanid

      JOIN (SELECT @prevLoan := 0, 
                   @amnt := 0) t

Produces...                      (Total Paid)   (for reversing calc)
tid   loanid  entrydate    amount   NewBal      Running Totals   prevLoan
6     1       2013-06-07   1100     3600        1100             1
3     1       2013-06-02   1000     2500        2100             1
1     1       2013-06-01   1500     1500        3600             1
7     2       2013-06-09   1000     2500        1000             2
2     2       2013-06-01   1500     1500        2500             2
4     3       2013-06-04   2300     2300        2300             3
5     5       2013-06-04   2000     2000        2000             5
```

Comment: wow... let me give it a try...
BTW I was grouping by loan Id because I understood that it's necessary for the sum to be done, but maybe I'm wrong. The joing with loan I will still need for future adjustments to the query, since the loanid won't be the only info I need from the loan account. Do you think that will alter your answer too much? BTW again, I exemplified with an integer loanid, but in fact it may be a string, I thought that wouldn't matter but maybe it does...?

Comment: @JavierNovoaC., the addition of the actual loan table via join should have no extra bearing, just use it to grab the extra elements such as loan account, customer, whatever.  It's not actually needed for the ordering of transactions descending yet still grouped by loan.

Comment: well, it seems that it's not working. It still gives me the same result with the transactions sumed in the original order, not the reversed one :(

Comment: @JavierNovoaC., so do you want to see -- for example for load ID 1 on 2013-06-07 you want to see the  3,600.  Then on 2013-06-02 would be 2,500 and finally on 2013-06-01 has 1,500?  Almost like a mortgage amortization schedule showing the total amount going DOWNWARD?

Comment: no not exactly. I just want the sums added in the order the transactions are listed. If upwards, the amounts for each transaction get summed one by one until reaching a total. If downwards, the amounts for each transaction get summed one by one until reaching the VERY SAME total. The difference is just at the order in which transactions get summed up...

Comment: Hey! I got it! I just needed to GROUP by loanid and tr.entrydate, instead of just ordering it! But, a little question... didn't know that Group accepted the DESC keyword :-o because I tried to use group instead of order and accidentally left the DESC there, and worked! If I remove the DESC, it reverses, as expected... quite strange for me that DESC may be used on GROUP.... THANKS!

Comment: hoho guess what, not yet... I was filtering for a specific loanid just to make tests, and now I retired the filter and it gives me just one row, as if just every row of the resultset were belonging to the same group... I'll have to work on it a bit more...

Comment: ok, last comment... my error... on the condition updating the amount, instead of COMPARING prevLoan, I was assigning it again... LOL